# Json & json decoded code to simple html table using php

Tags: php, json, html-table

```
<?php
    

$jsondata = '{
    "error": false,
    "room": "#10",
    "class": "5th",
    "students": "5",
    "gen": "male",
    "studentsInfo": [
        {
            "name": "john",
            "age": "14y",
            "grade": "3rd",
            "roll#": "1st"
        },
        {
            "name": "ali",
            "age": "15y",
            "grade": "1st",
            "roll#": "5th"
        },
        {
            "name": "mnzr",
            "age": "17y",
            "grade": "2nd",
            "roll#": "4th"
        },
        {
            "name": "chauhan",
            "age": "12y",
            "grade": "1st",
            "roll#": "3st"
        },
        {
            "name": "lie",
            "age": "15y",
            "grade": "3rd",
            "roll#": "2nd"
        }
    ]
}';

    $cls = json_decode($jsondata);
    echo 'Room Number - ' . $cls->room . '<br>' . 'Class - ' . $cls->class . '<br>' . 'Students Number - ' . $cls->students . '<br>' . 'Gener - ' . $cls->gen . '<hr>';
    
?>
    
    <!-- Now I want to print the studentsinfo in the table as: -->
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>Grade</td>
                <td>Roll#</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But with the condition that the first class of students should be at the top, the second should be according to their grades ie first class then second class and then third class..

How I can achieve this.

Comment: I assume you are doing regular server side rendering here? And this is a PHP file on the server?

Comment: So sort your `$cls->studentsInfo` as needed

Comment: How to sort $cls->studentsInfo.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a server side php script that is going to be returned then yes you can easily achieve this.

Since you haven't given specific keys to each student the best way to do it is to loop through the array like so:

You can't have roll# as a object key as "#" is a comment in PHP.
You have to say rollNumber

See this example its working:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Roll#</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($cls->studentsInfo as $studentInfo): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $studentInfo->name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $studentInfo->age ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $studentInfo->grade ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $studentInfo->rollNumber ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is according to my question, now how to sort this table according to grade.

Comment: You wouldn't really be doing that inside an html template, after you have created the string of JSON. If you are getting this from a database, you sort it in that function. If you are just practicing this stuff, then you sort it before you make a JSON string, but then there isn't a point turning JSON into a string.  You only make a JSON string, before you send it to the browser.  I will try update the answer soon https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php This is probably one of the last time I will do PHP code lol